# OpenSSL X509 certificate to string

Tags: header, openssl, certificate, newline, x509

I am using following code (simplified little bit) to get certificate string from X509 structure. Basically PEM_write_bio_X509 function.

```
X509 *certificate...
....
BIO *bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem()), BIO_vfree);
if (!bio || !PEM_write_bio_X509(bio, certificate)) {
    // error handling
}
size_t keylen = BIO_pending(bio);
unique_ptr<char[]> key(new char[keylen]);
int len = BIO_read(bio, key.get(), (int)keylen);
if (len <= 0) {
    // error handling
}
string result = string(key.get(), len);
```

The result is correctly something like

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFLTCCAxUCCQDrAnFYOmsVkzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJB
VTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Is there any way (without converting it manually myself later) to get it directly from OpenSSL as one line string without header lines? Something like:

```
MIIFLTCCAxUCCQDrAnFYOmsVkzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADBWMQswCQYDVQQGEwJBVTETMBEGA1UECAwKU29tZS1TdGF0ZTEhMB8GA1UECgwYSW50ZXJuZXQgV2lkZ2l0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two OpenSSL functions that can help you to achieve this

[PEM_read_bio()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PEM_read_bio.html) can read your PEM-formatted certificate file (or any PEM-formatted file for that matter) and split it into its header and data.

You are subsequently interested in the contents obtained in the `data` pointer, encoded as base64 in a long string.  [EVP_EncodeBlock()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_EncodeInit.html) can give you that by giving it those contents as its second parameter.

A rough outline of your code :

```
ret = PEM_read_bio(bio, &name, &header, &data, &len);
if (!ret) {
    // error
}

// Make sure b64block is allocated to contain at least
//     4*ceil(len/3) + 1 bytes
blockLen = EVP_EncodeBlock(b64block, data, len);
// b64block now contains the desired base64 in blockLen relevant bytes,
//     plus a null-character

// Don't forget to OPENSSL_free the name, header and data pointers
```