# Write Cert to DER

Tags: c, soap, openssl, der, wsse

I'm trying to write a X509 Cert to DER format in memory. 
Writing it to a file works perfectly.

I need the Cert in PEM format without the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----" header, footer or newlines. I can't figure out how to do it directly so... 
I'm outputting to der and base64 encoding.

THIS WORKS.

```
int X509_to_DER_file(X509 *cert) {
  int res=0;

  out = BIO_new(BIO_s_file());
  if (NULL != out) {
    if(BIO_write_filename(out, "my.der") > 0) {
      res = i2d_X509_bio(out, cert);
    }
    BIO_free_all(out);
  }
 return (tres);
}
```

THIS DOES NOT.
It returns and mallocs the correct number of bytes and appears to write out to memory correctly but the resulting string is incorrect (the first 15 or so positions are correct).

```
char *X509_to_DER_mem(X509 *cert) {
  char *der = NULL;
  bio = BIO_new(BIO_s_mem());

  if (NULL != bio) {
    //load cert into bio
    if (0 == i2d_X509_bio(bio, cert)) {
      BIO_flush(bio);
      BIO_free(bio);
      return NULL;
    }

   der = (char *) malloc(bio->num_write + 1);
   if (NULL == der) {
       BIO_free(bio);
       return NULL;
   }

   memset(der, 0, bio->num_write + 1);
   BIO_read(bio, der, bio->num_write);
   // Appears to work put "der" is incomplete. 
   BIO_free(bio);
 }

 return der;
}
```

Comment: Check the return value of `BIO_read`

Comment: BTW, I don't think you are supposed to use internal fields of BIO directly.. it is supposed to be an opaque type.

Comment: Is `bio` some kind of global?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It returns and mallocs the correct number of bytes and appears to
>   write out to memory correctly but the resulting string is incorrect

The result of `i2d_X509_bio()` is not a (zero-terminated) string, but a bunch of bytes. If you try to write it to a file as a string, it might look incomplete because you might encounter a 0-byte at a location before you reach the end. So in addition to the `char *` result, your function `X509_to_DER_mem()` will have to return the number of bytes that make up the result.

With regard to the memory `BIO`, another way of obtaining its data is with the [`BIO_get_mem_data()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/crypto/BIO_s_mem.html) function. Something like this:

```
char *ptr = NULL;
long len = BIO_get_mem_data(bio, &ptr);
der = malloc(len);
memcpy(der, ptr, len);
```

Finally, your *actual* question is

> I need the Cert in PEM format without the "-----BEGIN PRIVATE
>   KEY-----" header, footer or newlines.

Writing the certificate in DER format does not seem to give you what you need. [This answer to another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51510144) explains how you could use the function [`PEM_read_bio()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/PEM_read_bio.html) in combination with [`EVP_EncodeBlock()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/EVP_EncodeInit.html) for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. . Generous, educational and useful.

Comment: My pleasure and welcome to StackOverflow. If this answer was useful and completely resolved your issue, please consider accepting it, as explained in [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)